# libgdx - when game launch from menu crash

Tags: java, android, libgdx

When i create a menu to my game the game crash only in android. When running it at desktop all work fine. When i press play and fo to game screen game crash !

```
public Screen setGameScreen() {
        game_screen = new GameScreen(this);

        setScreen(game_screen);
        return game_screen;
    }
```

Button code:

```
    private void generalUpdate(Vector3 touch, OrthographicCamera camera) {
        playbutton.addListener(new ChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void changed(ChangeEvent event, Actor actor) {
                game.setScreen(game.setGameScreen());
            }
        });
}
```

When i click play it takes too much to load in logCat i have this:

```
05-05 11:21:21.780: D/-heap(11311): GC_CONCURRENT freed 2157K, 17% free 14025K/16867K, paused 2ms+4ms
```

it starts from 45%

Edit: I have to add load screen?

Comment: I don't see any crash in your logcat output.

Comment: Why are you calling setScreen(...) twice? The setGameScreen() method will already tell the game to set the current screen to the newly created instance... and then within your listener, you tell to set it again...

Comment: @evident ohh thanks !!!! it take some time to start the game maybe is normal.
Thanks for your answers !

Comment: You're welcome... Are you doing any blocking stuff when creating the GameScreen? Loading images, music, models? You should think about doing this using the AssetManager, which will do this asynchronously. You then can maybe add a little wait screen showing the user you are currently loading the game. Usually, changing the screen doesn't take very long...

Comment: Oh yes ! i have Assets class if you mean that and i load it at start with mainmenu !